# Sitemaps for domain and subdirectory that was subdomain before

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, subdirectory, sitemap

I have a Wordpress site (example.com) and subdomain (sub.example.com). They have separate Wordpress dashboards and were working like 2 separate websites. Now we redesigned both websites and want to move subdomain to a subdirectory, so it will look like this: sub.example.com to example.com/sub, but they still have 2 separate Wordpress dashboards and work as 2 separate websites basically.

My question is, what should I do with sitemaps? As before we had 2 separate properties on Search Console with 2 different sitemaps submitted. Now, if I understand right, subdirectory can't be considered as separate property on Search Console. So, what kind of sitemap should I create and how? Before we used All in One SEO plugin, now switched to Yoast, both plugins create sitemaps for you automatically.

Would appreciate some input on this as I'm really confused and not developer or have technical SEO knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is probably a better fit on [webmasters.se], because it is not related to programming, which is the topic here.

Answer (score 0):

sub-domain and folders in root directory almost acts same, if folder is having a separate cms.

for better understanding create a site map here, https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/
you will see only root urls here that means you have to place separate sitemaps in root folder as well as another folder. (i.e. public_html and other folder)

Give a proper path in google analytics dashboard e.g http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml, http://yourdomain.com/folder/sitemap.xml